# YML Deep Merge with YQ

Tags: merge, yaml, yq

I need to perform what you might call a *deep merge* between two YML files.

Where there are two matching paths the child nodes should be aggregated, that includes array values.  Where there is a path match on a terminal node the value from the second file wins.

For exmaple:

INPUT: a.yml

```
a:
  a:a
  b:b

b:
  a:a
```

INPUT: b.yml

```
a:
  a:1
  c:1

c:
  a:1
```

REQUIRED OUTPUT:

```
a:
  a:1
  b:b
  c:1
b:
  a:a
c:
  a:1
```

The closest I have got to this using `yq` is:

`yq eval-all '. as $item ireduce ({}; . *+d $item )' *.yml`

```
a: a:1 c:1
b: a:a
c: a:1
```

as you can see `a:` branch is replaced entirely from the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YAML requires at least one whitespace character after the `:` to make it an object with key and value. In your sample file `a.yml` containing

```yaml
a:
  a:a
  b:b
```

the value of `.a` is simply the string `a:a b:b`. There are no paths `.a.a` or `.a.b`.

---

With the necessary whitespace added, your attempt works as expected (spelling out the input file arguments because order matters: the latter will overwrite the former).

```bash
yq eval-all '. as $item ireduce ({}; . *+d $item )' a.yml b.yml
```

```yaml
a:
  a: 1
  b: b
  c: 1
b:
  a: a
c:
  a: 1
```

Tested with [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) v4.35.1